# All reporting api services returning 404 response

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, mongodb

I am currently enabling xDB on an Sitecore 8.2.5 install that has recently been upgraded from an 8 initial release. It has never had xDB enabled. I'm getting some issues where data appears to be added to the mongoDB, but when I access the any of the reports I'm getting 404 errors:

```
somesite/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/786FBA3A4573445EA74504E3CA5E48C1/all?&dateGrouping=by-week&&dateFrom=12-07-2017&dateTo=12-10-2017&keyGrouping=collapsed
```

Log files don't to show anything out of the normal.

The pages where I see this are the custom analytics graph on the launchpad as well as in the experience analytics dashboard.

I don't really understand why this is happening. The xdb remote processing configs are disabled, the route exists in the routes table:

```
sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/{site}/{segments}/{keys}
```

Has anyone seen this error before?
Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Further on investigation it appears that there isnt any data in the sitecore analytics Facts or Dimensions tables. The following error is in log:
[image]

I have also started from a clean set of MongoDB's and SQL analytics db.

Comment: This could be an upgrade issue, maybe you missed a step, Have you tried comparing files/configs of vanilla instance of sitecore with you upgraded instance?

Comment: Hey Ahmed, yup I've tried this. I have compared the vanilla configs and I'm not seeing any differences associated with analytics. I have also compared all the Sitecore binaries and the /sitecore folder using winmerge and am also not seeing any notable differences.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely possible that following SqlMappingEntity has been declared more then once.

```
<SqlMappingEntity type="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.SqlMappingEntity, Sitecore.Analytics.Sql">
    <Table>Fact_FormStatisticsByContact</Table>
    <Routine>Add_FormStatisticsByContact</Routine>
</SqlMappingEntity>
```

Likely reason: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/282795

Remove all duplicate SqlMappingEntity elements from your configs and see if this helps.

Comment: This almost solved the issue as we did have duplicates. The actual issue was related to a customized DefaultHttpControllerSelector which for some reason has blocked access to any routes within the analytics area. The customisation of the httpcontrollerselector was similar to: [link](http://wp-bartbovendeerdtcom.azurewebsites.net/sitecore-8-webapi-v2-mvc-and-attribute-routing/)